# App crashes if nothing entered

Tags: java, android, crash, calculator

Ok i'm trying to create simple calculator app, but it crashes when nothing entered i tried conditionals but it didn't work.
So if anyone could help me that would be nice.
Thank you very much!!

P.S. sorry for bad english

```
public class Kalkulator extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kalkulator);
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

}

public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFirstNumber);
    EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSecondNumber);
    EditText e3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etThirdNumber);
    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvresult);
    String a = e1.getText().toString();
    String b = e2.getText().toString();
    String c = e3.getText().toString();
    String er = "Ukucaj neki broj";
    double num1 = Double.parseDouble(a);
    double num2 = Double.parseDouble(b);
    double num3 = Double.parseDouble(c);

    if ( a.equals("") || b.equals("") || c.equals("")) {
        t1.setText(er);
    } else {
        double sum = (num1*4) + (num2*5) + (num3*5);
        t1.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: any exception stack trace in console?

Comment: Please give us details about exception

Comment: Wild guess here. If (a, b, c) can be an empty string, then parseDouble probably throws NumberFormatException. Try moving the parsing code to the else block

Comment: please post the exception in the log cat!!

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wild guess here. If (a, b, c) can be an empty string, then parseDouble probably throws NumberFormatException. Try moving the parsing code to the else block.

Answer (score -1):

this problem because the user not enter any number in `e1`,`e2`and`e3`.
when compiler go to line `String a = e1.getText().toString();` he not find any text in `e1` to convert to String !! and so on ..

i solve it by this function

```
private boolean isEmpty(EditText etText) {
if (etText.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
         }
}
```

and  test the edit text is empty or no

you can use it in your code set this function  and use it

**your code**

```
  package com.ftech.kalkulatorzamalumaturu;

  import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.TextView;

 public class Kalkulator extends AppCompatActivity {
  String a ,b ,c ;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_kalkulator);
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

 }

 public void onButtonClick(View v) {
   final  EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFirstNumber);
   final  EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSecondNumber);
   final  EditText e3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etThirdNumber);
   final  TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvresult);
      if (isEmpty(e1 )==false){
                          a = e1.getText().toString();
                             }

    if (isEmpty(e2 )==false){ 
                         b = e2.getText().toString();
                       }


    if (isEmpty(e3 )==false){
                        c = e3.getText().toString();
                       }


String er = "Ukucaj neki broj";
double num1 = Double.parseDouble(a);
double num2 = Double.parseDouble(b);
double num3 = Double.parseDouble(c);

if ( a.equals("") || b.equals("") || c.equals("")) {
    t1.setText(er);
} else {
    double sum = (num1*4) + (num2*5) + (num3*5);
    t1.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
}



}

private boolean isEmpty(EditText etText) {
if (etText.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
         }
}
 }
```

Comment: Sorry if it's a dumb question but what does "set iny think" mean

Comment: Also, "when compiler go to line String a = e1.getText().toString()" ? What does the compiler have to do with anything? It obviously compiles just fine.

Comment: when i type a,b,c in parsing part get red lines, and if i create new strings the strings in condition part get red lines

Comment: @F.Pajic try now i set `final`

Comment: Some? You really should post the exceptions you are getting, otherwise wild guesses are all we can offer.

Comment: Yes thanks!! I'm new to programming and this was actually my first application and i learnt allot now thank to you guys. Thanks!!!

Comment: you are welcome,  if my answer help you to solve your problem accept it

Comment: Recreated my comment as an answer so you can accept that ;)

Comment: @OskarHýbl   Good luck :)

Comment: @MohammedOsh likewise :)

Comment: @F.Pajic Thanks for accepting! MohammedOsh, seems like I won :))